# Browser page becomes unresponsive on sign in using firebase google login

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm using React.js and firebase to build a web app. Using firebase, when the auth state changes as the user signs in with google, the pages is supposed to be redirected to the "/home" route. instead, it signs in and then "freezes". The page becomes unresponsive. I have checked the console logs on the localhost:3000 page. It keeps throwing a warning multiple times. see below
Kindly help me fix this.

> Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging. See https://crbug.com/1038223. Command line switch --disable-ipc-flooding-protection can be used to bypass the protection

below is my code.

```
//Header.js component
import { signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { selectUserEmail, selectUserName, selectUserPhoto, setSignOutState, setUserLoginDetails } from "../features/user/userSlice";
import { auth, provider } from "../firebase";

//header component.
const Header = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const userEmail = useSelector(selectUserEmail);
  const userName = useSelector(selectUserName);
  const userPhoto = useSelector(selectUserPhoto);

  // moniter auth state. if user signs in , redirect him to homepage
  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(
      async (user) => {
        if (user) {
          setUser(user);
          navigate("/home");
        }
      },
      [userName, userEmail, userPhoto]
    );
  });
  //handle auth ftn
  const handleAuth = async () => {
    provider.addScope("profile");
    provider.addScope("email");
    if (!userName) {
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
      setUser(result.user).catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      });
      console.log(result);
    } else if (userName) {
      auth
        .signOut()
        .then(() => {
          dispatch(setSignOutState());
          navigate("/");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert(error.message);
        });
    }
  };

  //dispatch ftn
  const setUser = (user) => {
    dispatch(
      setUserLoginDetails({
        name: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
        photo: user.photoURL,
      })
    );
  };

  //UI of the COMPONENT
  return (
    <Nav>
      <Logo>
        <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="Disney Logo" />
      </Logo>
      {!userName ? (
        <Login onClick={handleAuth}>LOGIN</Login>
      ) : (
        <>
          <NavMenu>
            <a href="/home">
              <img src="/images/home-icon.svg" alt="home" />
              <span>HOME</span>
            </a>
            <a href="/search">
              <img src="/images/search-icon.svg" alt="home" />
              <span>SEARCH</span>
            </a>
            <a href="/watchlist">
              <img src="/images/watchlist-icon.svg" alt="home" />
              <span>WATCHLIST</span>
            </a>
            <a href="/original">
              <img src="/images/original-icon.svg" alt="home" />
              <span>ORIGINALS</span>
            </a>
            <a href="/movies">
              <img src="/images/movie-icon.svg" alt="home" />
              <span>MOVIES</span>
            </a>
            <a href="/series">
              <img src="/images/series-icon.svg" alt="home" />
              <span>SERIES</span>
            </a>
          </NavMenu>
          <Signout>
            <UserImg src={userPhoto} alt={userName} />
            <DropDown>
              <span onClick={handleAuth}>Sign out</span>
            </DropDown>
          </Signout>
        </>
      )}
    </Nav>
  );
};

//App.js code

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Login from "./components/Login";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />}></Route>
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your `useEffect` has no dependencies, this can cause an infinite loop, which is probably what happened. You probably be ok here with an empty dependency array: `[]`, the effect will then run once when the component "mounts".

Comment: added username as dependency. IT WORKED like a charm. thank you so much man :).

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        navigate("/home");
      }
    });
  }, [userName]);
```

just added userName as a dependency and it fixed it. The problem was that without the dependency, it was throwing an infinite loop.